# Using Log4J with JUnit and Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, docker, junit, log4j

I have a Gradle project with JUnit tests that run when the project is built.

The project is also dockerized. Inside the docker container the project is run with Java and Tomcat.

All of the tests pass, but I am getting an error in the console:

```
com.myapp.MyObjectTest > testGetData STANDARD_ERROR
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tomcat/website/webapps/app/logs/logFile.log (No such file or directory)
```

In my log4j xml file, I have this appender:

```
<appender name="rolling" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/tomcat/website/webapps/app/logs/logFile.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />    
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} %F: %m%n" /> 
    </layout>
</appender>
```

There are classes in the JUnit test that are referencing that use log files.

I understand why I am getting this error; it's because the JUnit tests are being run outside of the docker container so it can't find the `/tomcat/website/webapps/app/logs/` directory. I guess I can use the logs directory in the source folder, but I can't change that in the log4j xml file because when the project is actually running, it won't log correctly.

Any idea how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you run the `JUnit` tests on the host running the `Tomcat` container. If all you need is to get access to the log files in the `../app/logs` directory of the container then you could create the docker container with a volume. For example with [Gradle docker plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/):

```
task createBuildContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
 doFirst {
    def hostPath = (file("/path/on/host")).getAbsolutePath()
}

 volumes = [ '/tomcat/website/webapps/app/logs/' ]
 binds = [ (hostPath) : '/tomcat/website/webapps/app/logs/' ]
...
}
```

It will share the logs between host and container and the `JUnit` tests will be able to read them. Hope it helps

Comment: JUnit is being run when the project is built by Gradle, either on my local machine while I'm working on the project or via Jenkins (our build automation tool). The project gets dockerized after I build it with Gradle, so the docker container doesn't exist yet.